# Pushing value into a multidimensional array

Tags: javascript, arrays, multidimensional-array, push, javascript-objects

I have surfed the problem but couldn't get any possible solution ..

Let's say i have a var like this

```
var data = [
           {
              'a':10,
              'b':20,
              'c':30
           },
           {
              'a':1,
              'b':2,
              'c':3
           },
           {
              'a':100,
              'b':200,
              'c':300
           }];
```

Now , i need a multidimensional array like

```
var values = [[10,1,100],    //a
              [20,2,200],    //b
              [30,3,300]];   //c
```

What i have tried is

```
var values = [];
for(var key in data[0])
{
   values.push([]);   // this creates a multidimesional array for each key
   for(var i=0;i<data.length;i++)
   {
     // how to push data[i][key] in the multi dimensional array
   }
}
```

**Note :** `data.length` and **number of keys** keeps changing and i just want to be done using `push()` without any extra variables. Even i don't want to use extra `for` loops

If you guys found any duplicate here , just put the link as comment without downvote

Answer (score 8):

Try this:

```
var result = new Array();

for(var i = 0; i < data.length; i++) {
  var arr = new Array();
  for(var key in data[i]) {
    arr.push(data[i][key]);
  }
  result.push(arr);
}
```

also if you don't want the 'arr' variable just write directly to the result, but in my opinion code above is much more understandable:

```
for(var i = 0; i < data.length; i++) {
  result.push(new Array());
  for(var key in data[i]) {
    result[i].push(data[i][key]);
  }
}
```

---

Ok, based on your comment I have modified the the loop. Please check the solution and  mark question as answered if it is what you need. Personally I don't understand why you prefer messy and hard to understand code instead of using additional variables, but that's totally different topic.

```
for(var i = 0; i < data.length; i++) {
  for(var j = 0; j < Object.keys(data[0]).length; j++) {
    result[j] = result[j] || new Array();
    console.log('result[' + j + '][' + i + ']' + ' = ' + data[i][Object.keys(data[i])[j]])
    result[j][i] = data[i][Object.keys(data[i])[j]];
  }
}
```

Comment: What is wrong with this answer? It's working perfectly well: http://jsfiddle.net/g4jeG/

Comment: @Imperative Yupp it works and i already know this but i just want to know is there any other simpler way to achieve this ...?

Comment: I have added version that don't need extra 'arr' variable, check it out. If something is still wrong - please let us know :)

Comment: @yaki See my question well .. Output i need is 10,1,100,20,2,200,30,3,300

Comment: @yaki my need is row=key,col=data.length .. Yours is row=data.length,col=key

Comment: Please check the latest change, maybe it's what you are looking for

Comment: Because you don't know the array exists or not, you need to use 'result[x][y] = variable' or check if it exists: 

if(!result[j])
  result.push(new Array()); 

Similarly you may simply replace the second assignment with: 

if(!result[j][i])
result[j].push(data[i][Object.keys(data[i])[j]]);